# Allow Only Specific Profiles to Change Owner

Tags: formula, validation-rule, ownership

Below is my `Validation Rule`. It does not allow a user with the `Profile` of 'management' to change the owner of a record.

```
AND (
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    OR(
        PRIORVALUE (OwnerId ) <> $User.Id,
        $Profile.Name  <>  'Sales Administrator',
        $Profile.Name  <>  'Management',
        $Profile.Name  <>  'System Administrator'
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tested this for the other profiles listed in this validation rule?

Comment: Guess it only works for the system admin, the other two profiles display the error message from the validation rule.

Comment: First thing that I would try is using the ID's instead of the name, it eliminates the possibility of spelling errors. Then I would try and just test one profile at a time. Remove the others from the validation rule, run the first and if it works then add the next and test it, and then keep going till you find the first one that doesn't work.

Comment: Nooooo not hard-coded Ids. :(

Comment: Adding just the Sales Administrator and using the ID# vs the Profile name did not allow a user with that profile type to make the change. But removing the system admin did prevent me from making a change as a system admin.

Comment: AND ( ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
      OR(
PRIORVALUE (OwnerId ) <> $User.Id,
$Profile.Name  <>  '00eE0000000j73k'
))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always *not* be one of those profiles, since you can only have one. It sounds like what you want is to throw an error if your first criterion is true (owner has changed) and none of the subsequent criteria are true (running user is either current owner or whitelisted profile). In that case, use `NOT(OR(...))` with equality comparisons, instead of `OR(...)` with inequality comparisons.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    NOT(OR(
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = $User.Id,
        $Profile.Name = "System Administrator",
        $Profile.Name = "Sales Administrator",
        $Profile.Name = "Management"
    ))
)
```

Comment: I want the listed profiles to be the only users that can change the ownership. I replaced the provided code and it still shows the validation error for a user of the Management profile, but does allow the system admin to change ownership without an error.

Comment: Correction, I can change only if I am the owner already, so the first part of the rule is working.

Comment: I think I see what's going on. Perhaps I misinterpreted what is going on with `PRIORVALUE`. You want these select profiles to be able to change owner even if they aren't the current owner? @NicoleArd

Comment: I'll add more explanation if the current rule is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: Correct, basically limit the ability from anyone from changing the ownership of the record

Comment: @Nicole so...`NOT(OR(...))` should work, right? You should throw an error whenever all of the inner clauses are false.

Comment: Brillant! I should have asked sooner, but half the learning is solving the puzzle :) It appears to be functioning as I need, thanks for the assistance - @Adrian